# i can't create ftp conection with spring and maven

Tags: spring, maven

I have tried to make a connection to an ftp server, and although in the test section it does it perfectly, when I try to put it in the main class of the project it simply tells me that the namespace is not found, I am using spring with Maven.
pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-ftp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.release}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`
```

ftpOutbound.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.3.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="user.properties"/>

 <!--  <context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.prospringintegration.ftp"/>-->

    <bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cachingSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="ftpClientFactory"/>
    </bean>



 <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="ftpOutbound"
                channel="ftpChannel"
                remote-directory="/"
                session-factory="cachingSessionFactory" />

     <!--       <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <int:retry-advice />
        </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>-->

         <int:channel id="ftpChannel">
          <int:queue/>
         </int:channel>   

</beans>
```

and the main class is

```
    import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ftpOutbound.xml");

        MessageChannel ftpChannel = context.getBean("ftpChannel", MessageChannel.class);

        File fileToSendA = new File("text.txt");

        Message<File> messageA = MessageBuilder.withPayload(fileToSendA).build();


        ftpChannel.send(messageA);
    }
}
```

But when I execute it the following error appears

```
ago 28, 2017 11:08:27 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMACIËN: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ftpOutbound.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 614 in XML document from class path resource [ftpOutbound.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd; lineNumber: 614; columnNumber: 71; src-resolve: No se puede resolver el nombre 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' para un componente 'attribute group'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

help me please!!

Comment: `ftpOutbound.xml´ is not found. add a slash in front of the file name and try again

Comment: Add stacktraces as text, not as an image

Comment: hello Jens, I already tried and still gives the same error

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: It is located in : src/main/resources

Comment: I have in my IDE another problem when I write the location of the scheme, I mark the warning:
Class 'org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor' is marked deprecated